# In tournament modes, how do you earn and lose money?

Tags: the-finals

In Quick Cash tournament, you earn $10.000 when you bank a cash box, but the amount seems different during overtime ($22.000).  You also earn some money when you capture a cash box, but I'm not sure how much.  I also saw some money flowing in from time to time, perhaps when I kill or revive someone?  Again, not sure how much exactly.
Finally, you lose 30% of your team cash if the team gets wiped.

I have no experience with Bank It tournament.  Also I'm wondering if there are differences between ranked and unranked tournament.

Can someone summarize how to gain and lose cash (and the exact amounts) in these game modes (Quick Cash tournament ranked and unranked, Bank It ranked and unranked)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I understand after a few tests (with [version 1.5.0](https://www.reachthefinals.com/patch-notes-7)).

**Bank It tournament, ranked or not, all rounds except final round**

- Killing an opponent: $200
- Capturing a cash box: $1000
- Putting a cash box in the ATM: $2000
- Banking a cash box:

  - Cash box 1 and 2: $10.000
  - Cash box 3 and 4: $15.000
  - Cash box 5 and 6: $22.000
- Wiping a team: steal 30% of their total cash